# Ruby on Rails: Show old child attributes in a nested formular

Tags: ruby, model, devise, ruby-on-rails-4, formula

I'm trying to show the attributes of a `one-on-one-relationship` in the edit formula of a model. Sadly only the "real" attributes of the parent model itself are shown.

Here are some code snippets, thanks in advance! (I'm using `Devise` as the authentication system, thus I'm using `resource` in the form)

models/parent.rb

```
class Parent < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one  :child, dependent: :destroy, autosave: true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :user_info, allow_destroy: true
end
```

models/child.rb

```
class Child < ActiveRecord::Base    
  belongs_to :parent, inverse_of: :child, readonly: true
end
```

parents/edit.html.erb

```
<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, 
             html: { id: 'registration_form', 
             class: 'form-inline' }, 
             url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>

  <%= render 'form_parent_information', f: f %>  // Attributes from the 
                                                 // parent render perfectly!

  <% resource.build_child if resource.build_child.nil? %>

  <%= f.fields_for :child do |f| %>
    <%= render 'shared/nested_child_form', f: f %>
  <% end %>

<% end %>
```

If I enter fresh input, the form executes as it should and creates a new child, if not already there.

**Additionally:** I didn't want to bomb you with all the additional code, so I minimized it, but I'm have other childs inside of this one child and (of course) I've got the same problem there. Also those children-children become deleted when left empty! Why is that? :D

But first: How would I display attributes of children in my form? I also tried to use `resource.build_child(child.attributes)`, though it didn't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED**

There it comes, I'm still new to Rails and especially its **Basics** ;-)

This is the important part:

```
<% resource.build_child if resource.build_child.nil? %>

<%= f.fields_for :child do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/nested_child_form', f: f %>
<% end %>
```

`resource.build_child.nil?` will always report `true`, because I haven't called the method yet and thus it's `nil`. I need this validation in the `parents/new.html.erb` though, because I am actually creating a new object of type Child there. I do not need it in `parents/edit.html.erb`, because I already got a Child item in here, in the Database!

Simply comment it out and watch it work!